# Postgres - How to find a row with the biggest intersection of a certain column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-10

I have a table called `Protocols` which holds a column called `keyWords` which is of type `TEXT[]`.
Given an array of strings, how do I get the row with the biggest intersection of the `keyWords` column and the given array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function (that can be useful elsewhere as well):

```
create or replace function array_intersect(anyarray, anyarray)
returns anyarray language sql as $function$
    select case 
        when $1 is null then $2
        else
            array(
                select unnest($1)
                intersect
                select unnest($2)
            )
        end;
$function$;
```

Query:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        id, keywords,
        cardinality(array_intersect(keywords, '{a,b,d}')) as common_elements
    from protocols
    )
select * 
from cte
where common_elements = (select max(common_elements) from cte)
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=12efd4e5b6ba22f2c79f237b2b2058cc)

In case you do not like the function:

```
with cte as (
    select id, count(keyword) as common_elements
    from protocols
    cross join unnest(keywords) as keyword
    where keyword = any('{a,b,d}')
    group by 1
    )
select id, keywords, common_elements
from cte
join protocols using(id)
where common_elements = (select max(common_elements) from cte);
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=237dcd28710fbb46bff89c8c62153a67)